How to add more user fields into a profile table with Laravel & Livewire
I am new to Laravel and am trying to add more fields to the jetstreams profile page.
in my app\action\fortify I have this:
class UpdateUserProfileInformation implements UpdatesUserProfileInformation
{

    public function update(User $user, array $input): void
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:1024'],
            //user profiles
            'language' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255']
        ])->validateWithBag('updateProfileInformation');

        if (isset($input['photo'])) {
            //$user->updateProfilePhoto($input['photo']);
            $this->updateProfilePhoto($user, $input);
        }

        if ($input['email'] !== $user->email &&
            $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
            $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $input);
        } else {
            $user->forceFill([
                'name' => $input['name'],
                'email' => $input['email']
            ])->save();

            //update / create profile
            $user->profile()->updateOrCreate([],
            [
                'language' => $input['language'] ?? $user->profile->language,
            ]);

        }
    }

and in resource\view\profile\update-profile-information-from.blade.php I added this:
<!-- Language -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <x-label for="language" class="form-label" value="{{ __('Language') }}" />
            <select id="language" class="form-select {{ $errors->has('language') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                wire:model.defer="state.language">
                <option disabled>Select a language</option>
                @foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $key => $language)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}"
                        {{ (auth()->user()->profile->language ?? config('app.locale')) === $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                        {{ $language }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <x-input-error for="language" />
        </div>

This doesn't save to the DB, and when I enter a language manually into DB it doesn't reflect in the view either. What am I missing here? Thank you.
Laravel version: 10
